# Preventing Typeclass constraints from propagating upwards through a transformer stack

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers

I have a lot of databases (and other sources of data) that I use at work, each one is slightly different, maybe a different backend, or requires slightly different information be provided at runtime, so whenever I write a program in haskell I have to juggle a lot of logic, withDB this and ConnectInfo that, pass around this handle here or there and it ends up swamping the logic of my programs, which are generally very simple.

So I decided to write a little library to just do all the heavy lifting for me.

I feel like I am approaching my goals, but I'm not quite there.  In this I have two pretend databases, `A` and `B`, one just requires a query, but the other one requires that I specify the name of the database I want to query.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.22  runghc --package mtl --package mysql-simple

{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, LambdaCase, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module West.Databases.Types where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

import Database.MySQL.Simple as MS
import Database.MySQL.Simple.QueryParams as MS
import Database.MySQL.Simple.QueryResults as MS

newtype DBName = DBName String deriving Eq

data DBState = DBState {
    aDBConn :: Maybe Connection
  , bDBConn :: Maybe (Connection, DBName)
}

class MonadResource m => MonadDB m where
  liftDB :: DBAction a -> m a

runB :: DBName -> BQuery a -> DBAction a
runB dbname (BQuery q p f) = BAction dbname q p f

runA :: AQuery a -> DBAction a
runA (AQuery q p f) = AAction q p f

instance (MonadState DBState m, MonadResource m, MonadIO m) => MonadDB m where
  liftDB (AAction q p f) = f <$> do
    (aDBConn <$> get) >>= \case
      Nothing -> do
        newconn <- snd <$> allocate (MS.connect (undefined :: ConnectInfo)) MS.close
        modify (\dbs -> dbs { aDBConn = Just newconn })
        liftIO (MS.query newconn q p)
      Just aconn -> liftIO (MS.query aconn q p)
  liftDB (BAction newdbname q p f) = f <$> do
    (bDBConn <$> get) >>= \case
      Nothing -> undefined
      Just (bconn, dbname) -> if dbname == newdbname
        then liftIO (MS.query bconn q p)
        else do
          -- MS.query "use newdbname"
          liftIO (MS.query bconn q p)

data DBAction a =
    forall r p. AAction Query p ([r] -> a)
  | forall r p. BAction DBName Query p ([r] -> a)

instance Functor DBAction where
  fmap f (AAction q p fr) = AAction  q p (f . fr)
  fmap f (BAction dbname q p fr) = BAction dbname q p (f . fr)

-- TODO
instance Applicative DBAction
instance Monad DBAction

data BQuery a = forall r p. BQuery Query p ([r] -> a)
data AQuery a = forall r p. AQuery Query p ([r] -> a)
```

This allows me to write code like this

```
data UID
data Password

me :: AQuery (UID, DBName)
me = AQuery "select uid,customerdb from users where user_name rlike 'me@blah.com'" () undefined

friends :: UID -> BQuery Int
friends uid = BQuery "select count(*) from friends where uid = ?" uid undefined

userCount :: AQuery Int
userCount = AQuery "select count(*) from users" () toCount
  where
    toCount ((Only i):_) = i
    toCount _ = error "userCount should not occur"

userAuth :: UID -> Password -> AQuery Bool
userAuth uid pass = AQuery "select count(*) from users where uid = ? and password = ?" (uid, pass)
  (\c -> head c > (0 :: Int))
```

and also compose actions of different databases into procedures that I can run liftDB on.  This finds a user on a primary database, then queries said database for more in depth info about that user.

```
myFriends :: DBAction Int
myFriends = do
  (uid, dbname) <- runA me
  runB dbname (friends uid)
```

The problem is that the `msyql/postgresql-simple` libraries both have very similar `query` functions with the following types

```
query :: (ToRow q, FromRow r) => Connection -> Query -> q -> IO [r]
query :: (QueryParams q, QueryResults r) => Connection -> Query -> q -> IO [r]
```

which causes the `ToRow/QueryParams/FromRow/QueryResults` to propagate up into the `MonadDB` class, which probably shouldn't happen, but I can't figure out how to prevent it.  I feel like `DBAction` should somehow contain the logic necessary to run the query and update some state...

Comment: My gut feeling is that the backend specfific constraints should somehow show up in the *instances* of your custom class (so that you would have one instance per backend). I haven't thought about it for more than a few seconds though, and so I might be talking nonsense.

Comment: I'm fine with whatever, so long as it is simple.  My end goal is to be able to add `resourceT` and `StateT DBState` layers to the concrete type in whatever app I'm writing and if I happen to decide to query any database, it will connect and return results and clean up and I don't have to care.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a bit, I found the solution I was looking for.

```
data DBAction a =
    forall p r. (QueryParams p, QueryResults r) => AAction Query p ([r] -> a)
  | forall p r. (QueryParams p, QueryResults r) => BAction DBName Query p ([r] -> a)
  -- forall p r. (FromRow r, ToRow r) => .... etc.

data AQuery a = forall r p. (QueryParams p, QueryResults r) => AQuery Query p ([r] -> a)
data BQuery a = forall r p. (QueryParams p, QueryResults r) => BQuery Query p ([r] -> a)
```

Then changing my queries so that they give concrete types to remove ambiguity when the time comes to query.

```
friends :: UID -> BQuery Int
friends uid = BQuery "select count(*) from friends where uid = ?" (undefined uid :: (Only Int)) toCount
  where
    toCount ((Only i):_) = i
    toCount _ = 0
```